# Using file_get_contents within admin but keep logged in

Tags: plugins, curl

Quick question as I'm not having much luck finding an answer on Google.

I'm running a file_get_contents in a plugin I'm building to get the HTML of another page within the admin. The HTML is showing but the problem is, it's loading the /wp-login.php page HTML and not the specified URL.

```
$data = file_get_contents('wp-admin/options-general.php?page=another_page');
$html_sourcecode_get = htmlentities($data);
echo $html_sourcecode_get;
```

Does anyone know how to keep the HTML grab as if I was still logged in? Do I need to use cURL with credentials?

Note: I have tried the wp file system alternative and it returns a critical error.

Thanks.

Comment: what are you doing that requires this? Why? There's not much context to the question. This is very unusual, and it's highly unlikely the result will work due to how the settings pages work. WP Filesystem should not be used for this, I'd advise against any remote request to a URL.

Comment: I need to grab an auto generated hash from another plugin.

Comment: it's almost guaranteed there is a better way to do this, after all that plugin has to generate the hash somehow and display it then store it somewhere, you should ask their support routes or in one of their discords/forums/groups